# Need event when AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer displays on screen

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have an app that does face detection using frames off of `AVCaptureConnection` via `didOutputSampleBuffer`, and displays the video screen using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

The problem is that the newest iOS devices are so fast that the detection process completes before or as soon as the video screen displays. I'd like there to be a short delay after the screen displays before detection begins. I do not want to just use a timer, because it then becomes a bit inconsistent across different device speeds. What I'd like to do is be notified when the video screen has displayed, and then start detection. Currently, when the app decides to start doing face detection, the `AVCaptureConnection.enabled` is set `YES`, and the `UIView` containing the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is set to `hidden=NO`.

Is there such a notification I can hook into, such as a `CALayer` event? I can't find one.